# Methods in trait become volatile methods when mixed in concrete classes in 2.9.0-1 but not 2.8.1

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, volatile, traits, scala-2.9

I noticed this breaking (for me using it with OGNL) change in 2.9.0-1:

I find that, in 2.9, methods declared in a trait become volatile when mixed in a class:

Example in 2.9.0-1

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

trait SuperTrait {
    def getKnoll = "Kanutten"
}

class KlassWithKnoll extends SuperTrait {
    def getKnall = "Mars"

}

val qsc = classOf[KlassWithKnoll]
val knollGetter = qsc.getDeclaredMethod("getKnoll")
println("isVolatile: " + Modifier.isVolatile(knollGetter.getModifiers()))
```

This prints out

```
isVolatile: true
```

But in 2.8.1:

it prints out

```
isVolatile: false
```

This is actually a breaking change for me as OGNL refuses to execute volatile (why I don't know) in its expressions.

So - my question is; Why was this change made?

Comment: Is `getKnoll` and `getKnall` just a typo?

Comment: No, getKnoll is the mixed in method and is the one becoming volatile and I'm wondering why.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a volatile method.  What you are seeing is that the 0x0040 flag is set, which is ACC_VOLATILE for fields, but ACC_BRIDGE for methods.  Since the Modifier.isVolatile method takes an Int, it can't really tell you that what you're asking is not meaningful.

Comment: Why are methods with body in traits becoming bridge-methods in scala-2.9 as they were not in 2.8? Or is this another SO question?